# Как выровнять текст по левому краю

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть сценарий, который состоит из двух шагов, и я хочу выровнять текст, например:

```
Step1 : I am a boy........
my name is Ram
```

Но я хочу выровнять текст так, как показано ниже:

```
Step1 : I am a boy........
        my name is Ram
```

Я попробовал атрибуты `text-align` и `align` для `span`.

```css
p.steps {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step1 : </span> I am a boy................. my name is Ram</p>
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step2 : </span> There are many countries but I live in Australia </p>
Full pag
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to align left the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63776646/7394871) от участника  [@Muddasar Saiyed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8386150/muddasar-saiyed).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63776646/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Разметка table сделает свое дело:

```css
p.steps {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display:table; /* здесь */
}
p.steps span {
  display:table-cell; /* здесь */
  white-space:nowrap; /* и здесь */
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step1 : </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut pellentesque urna at ex fermentum egestas. Nullam convallis nec dolor finibus rhoncus. Nunc neque nisi,</p>
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step2 : </span> There are many countries but I live in Australia </p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776853/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Есть много возможных решений (table, flex, text-indent и т.д.), Но пока это упорядоченный список, я бы использовал `ol` и `li`, чтобы код был ***семантически правильными***. Вы можете создать свой собственный элемент в стиле списка с псевдоэлементом `:before`, который может реализовать `elementcounter`.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 3.5rem;
}
li:before {
  content: "Step " counter(elementcounter) ":";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>I am a boy...<br/> my name is Ram</li>
   <li>There are many countries but I live in Australia</li>
</ol>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776888/7394871) от участника  [@Jax-p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597017/jax-p).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Есть много способов сделать это. Вы можете реализовать это с помощью `flexbox`.

Добавьте `display: flex` к элементу `p`.

```css
p.steps {
  display: flex;

  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.step {
  display: block;
  
  color: #BB2812;
}

.step-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="steps">
  <span class="step">Step 1:</span>

  <span class="step-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada non ex consectetur posuere. Vestibulum in leo tempus dolor pharetra ultricies.
  </span>
</p>

<p class="steps">
  <span class="step">Step 2:</span>

  <span class="step-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada non ex consectetur posuere. Vestibulum in leo tempus dolor pharetra ultricies.
  </span>
</p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776876/7394871) от участника  [@Magiczne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7101876/magiczne).</sub>